# Multi-row SELECT query on SINGLE column

Tags: mysql, database-design

In my MySQL database I have two columns setup like this (for example):

```
series_id   category_id
    1            1
    1            2
    1            3
    2            1
    2            3
    3            2
    4            1
    4            2
```

What is the proper select query I can use to select the series_id when the category_id = 1 and 2?

Current query is this:

```
SELECT series_id 
FROM table 
WHERE category_id = '1' 
OR category_id = '2' 
GROUP BY series_id"
```

This does not retrieve any results:

```
SELECT series_id 
FROM table 
WHERE category_id = '1' 
AND category_id = '2' 
GROUP BY series_id
```

In regards to this example I would like it to return the two rows where the series_id is 1 and 2 so the result looks like this:

```
series_id
     1
     4
```

(Optional / Bonus) If it is possible to come up with another solution or utilize:

```
GROUP_CONCAT(category_id SEPARATOR ', ') AS category
```

for the returned series_id (s) from this query so the returned result is:

```
series_id    category
     1       1, 2, 3
     4       1, 2
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT   series_id
FROM     my_table
WHERE    category_id IN (1,2)
GROUP BY series_id
HAVING   COUNT(*) = 2
```

See it on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/07bde/1/0).

Note that if `(series_id, category_id)` are not guaranteed to be unique, you should replace `COUNT(*)` with the less performant `COUNT(DISTINCT category_id)`.

To return the grouped results, you can join against your table again:

```
SELECT series_id, GROUP_CONCAT(category_id)
FROM   my_table NATURAL JOIN (
  SELECT   series_id
  FROM     my_table
  WHERE    category_id IN (1,2)
  GROUP BY series_id
  HAVING   COUNT(*) = 2
) t
GROUP BY series_id
```

See it on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/07bde/2/0).

Comment: I tested the solution you provided and it works beautifully. I do have one more related question in regards to the same example mysql database table. What would you do if you want to retrieve results where WHERE category_id <> '1' AND category_id <> '3' so the only returned result in this example would be when the series_id = 3 ?

Comment: @RichVRed: You're looking for an anti-join.  In MySQL, the [two most performant approaches](http://explainextended.com/2009/09/18/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-mysql/) are via an outer join with a `NULL` test (similar to my answer above) or via `NOT IN` (similar to [Jon Woo's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12318244/623041)).  See them both on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/07bde/14).

Answer (score 2):

You need to have `SubQuery` to get the `series_id` so that later on you can use `GROUP_CONCAT.

```
SELECT series_ID, GROUP_CONCAT(category_id)
FROM tableName
WHERE series_ID IN
        (
            SELECT series_id
            FROM tableName
            WHERE Category_ID IN (1,2)
            GROUP BY seriesID
            HAVING COUNT(series_id) = 2
        )
GROUP BY series_ID
```

## [*SQLFiddle Demo*](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ec0e5/3)

Hope this helps you.

[image]

Comment: `COUNT(series_id)` may not perform as well as `COUNT(*)` and, in this case, is guaranteed to return the same results (as that column cannot be `NULL` due to the grouping operation).